# Clear text in ion-searchbar

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a search bar

```
<div id="search"><ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (change)="onChange($event)" (ionClear)="onCancel($event)" (ionInput)="onInput($event)" debounce="1"></ion-searchbar></div>
```

How do I, from the ts file clear the text the user has entered?

Here is the ts file function that tries to clear the search bar text.

```
.
private searchQuery: string = null;
.

  subscribeEvents() {
    this.events.subscribe('mapFilter:update', (data) => {
      this.employeeModel = data[0].employeeModel;
      if (data[0].fromClearFilters) {
        this.searchQuery = '';
      }
      this.getMarkers();
      this.getPosition();
    });
  }
```

`this.searchQuery = '';` does reset the filter but the text remains

Thanks

I am using Ionic 2

Answer (score 10):

First, add an identifier to your HTML element

`<ion-searchbar #mySearchbar ...>`

Then, import **ViewChild**:

`import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';`

Then, import  **Searchbar**

`import { Searchbar } from 'ionic-angular';`

Add it as a property:

`@ViewChild('mySearchbar') searchbar: Searchbar;`

Then, fire the onInput event and pass a null identifier (so your **onInput** event listener knows its you)

`this.searchbar.clearInput(null);`

Comment: It's a lot of work just to reset the input field. Unfortunelly I did not found a simple approach

Comment: Works fine on ionic 3

Answer (score 5):

**Workable Solution for ionic 5.4.16 & Angular 8.2.14 : Similar to DJ.'s answer, but for different version.**

1.Your ion-searchbar with **#mySearchbar** tag

```
  <ion-searchbar #mySearchbar1 #q (keyup.enter)="navigateSearchPage(q.value)"  placeholder="Search Product Name" style="padding: 0 10px" ></ion-searchbar>
```

2.Import and place the following code

```
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {IonSearchbar} from '@ionic/angular';

@ViewChild('mySearchbar', {static: false}) searchbar: IonSearchbar;
```

3.Clear the searchbar (place this code to the function that you will call to clear the searchbar.

```
this.searchbar.value = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `ngModel` in the search bar, you can just use the event sent to get the value like this:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)" [showCancelButton]="true"></ion-searchbar>
```

By doing that, you can clear the text in the `(ionCancel)` event by just doing:

```
  onCancel(ev) { 
    // Reset the field
    ev.target.value = '';
  }
```

Please notice that you don't need the `ngModel` binding and also you don't need to use the `(change)="..."` event.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advise, but I get this ts error:  `[ts] 
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
any`

Comment: Hmmm but that error is not happening in the plunker, right? Could you please check if your code is somehow different than the one in the plunker? (just the search bar in the html code). Or maybe try to replicate that error in the plunker so I can take a look and see which kind of event is being sent to the method...

Comment: Hi sebaferreras, I am using what might be considered a hack. I am getting the htmlelement and clicking on the search cancel button.

Comment: The issue you're using that hack for, is also happening in the plunker? There must be a better way to handle that scenario but I'd need to have it replicated there to take a look at it

Comment: Thanks.  I am busy on some other work at the moment, but when I get a chance, I will try get it running on plunker.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who is interested, the way this worked for me is:

```
@ViewChild('userSearchBar') searchbar: Searchbar;
```

then in your method:

```
this.searchbar._value='';
```

This works like a charm...

Answer (score 2):

ion-searchbar has a event called `ionClear`

```
(ionClear)="onClear($event)"
```

and then do whatever the logic from ts file.

Answer (score 1):

ion-searchbar has a method getInputElement which returns the native  element, as It returns a promise so do it like this and then ion-searchbar will be cleared.

```
//tested in Ionic ver 4.7.1 and working fine. 
document.querySelector('ion-searchbar').getInputElement().then((searchInput) => {
   searchInput.value = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Angular, aren´t you?

So you only have to clear the associated model "searchQuery" in controller. This way, angular will automatically clear the field;

```
this.searchQuery = '';
```

But ng-model should be bound to an object and not to an variable.

The means the the declaration of the variable should be something like:

```
 $scope.searchBox = {
    searchQuery: ''
 };
```

And change your search object to:

```
<ion-searchbar ... ng-model="searchBox.searchQuery" ... />
```

Comment: Hi Diogo, thanks for the advise. I am using Ionic 2 which is built on top of Angular 2. However, I do set the `this.searchQuery = '';`, which does clear the search results, but the actual text value in the search bar stays. My question is, how do I clear the text value the user typed into the search bar?

Comment: Are you sure that the text is not from input field autocomplete?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I don't understand? My html code is exactly like the code I posted above.

Comment: I have added more code samples. Let me know if you need more

Comment: strange.... i did the test with normal input and it works

http://plnkr.co/edit/AqE9PYReiYGdgFeCsBe5?p=preview

Comment: When I click the button to clear it, the button is in a popover. Then I capture the event, maybe it has something to do with that?

Comment: Also you are just using an `input type text`, where I am using an `ionic-searchbar`. When I look at the search bars html in firebug, it has child nodes and other attributes. So it is not as simple.

Comment: If you change this private searchQuery: string = null;

to this private searchQuery: string = "Test Field";

And reload the screen, the field has "Test Field" as value?

Comment: yes it does, when I set it in the constructor. So I cannot understand why it doesn't on the event.... When I click on the menuTogle after `searchQuery = '';` it does clear it. So it seems like a focus issue maybe.  I do have a popover where I set the event to clear it, maybe the popover is taking focus away.

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce in jfiddle, because I am using the ionic 2 libraries to create the popover etc. Sorry, I appreciate your help

Comment: I have updated my answer. 

I write the searchBox object definition with Angular1 sintax because i dont know angular2 sintax yet.

let me know it it works.

Comment: Thanks.  The Angular2/Ionic2 equivalent syntax is:  `[(ngModel)]="searchQuery"` and `this.searchQuery = '';` I think? It's what I already have. I am pretty new to Angular and Ionic.

Comment: I am trying to get a handle on the x (cancel) button and click it, do you think that's worth a try?

Comment: No, searchQuery = '' is an string not a object.

this is a object with an string attribute

this.searchBox = {
    searchQuery: ''
 }

I think if u change this, it will work

Comment: Change this
.
private  searchBox = {  searchQuery: ''  }
.

  subscribeEvents() {
    this.events.subscribe('mapFilter:update', (data) => {
      this.employeeModel = data[0].employeeModel;
      if (data[0].fromClearFilters) {
        this.searchBox.searchQuery = '';
      }
      this.getMarkers();
      this.getPosition();
    });
  }

than in the view


<ion-searchbar ... ng-model="searchBox.searchQuery" ... />

Comment: See the official documentation:

By default, ngModel watches the model by reference, not value. This is important to know when binding inputs to models that are objects (e.g. Date) or collections (e.g. arrays). If only properties of the object or collection change, ngModel will not be notified and so the input will not be re-rendered.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: That didn't work.  I understand what you are saying, it should map the object using ngModel.

Comment: I did manage to get the htmlElement for the cancel button and click that, and it works.  But not sure if it is not the most elegant solution.

Comment: It is definitely a focus issue, because your solution works when I click on the screen anywhere. It updates the page. I think the popover is taking focus away

Answer (score 0):

My answer builds on the answer DJ gave. I would just make this a response to his answer, but I don't have enough reputation. So, I'll make an answer of my own.

In order to get the clearInput() function to work. You need to pass it an event instance.

The best way to get this is to store the event object that gets passed in when you associate a function with an output event, something like `(ionInput)="myfunction($event)"`. Then just pass this into the clearInput function. If you put null, it will return an error like `Cannot find property 'target' of null`.

Example:

```
myFunction(event) {
    this.eventInstance = event;

    //the rest of your code
}
```